# CSS style sheet browser compatibility

Tags: html, css

I designed a site using css and div tag. It's working fine in IE 8 but it's not working properly in Firefox. Some resolution problem is coming in Firefox for some pages.

Is this problem due to css or div?

This is my css style sheet...

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

a.bottom:link,a.bottom:visited,a.bottom:active
{
/*display:compact;*/
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:normal;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#BF007F;
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}
a.bottomClick:link,a.bottomClick:visited,a.bottomClick:active
{/*display:compact;*/
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:normal;
color:#BF007F;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.MainHeading {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
color:#000000;
font-weight:bold;


}
.HeadingOfContentBox {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
color:#000000;
font-weight:bold;
}
.ContentText {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#000000;
font-weight:normal;

}

#ContentTable
{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
width:960px;

}


ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:4px;
margin:0px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li
{
background-image:url();
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:0px 5px; 
padding-left:18px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:1.5;
 margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
}
ul.unorder
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li.unorder
{
background-image:none;
background-position:0px 5px; 
padding-left:14px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#000000;
font-weight:normal;
}

A.topLink:Link {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#bf007f;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}
A.topLink:hover {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#bf007f;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}
A.topLink:Visited {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#bf007f;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}
#framecontentLeft{
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width:320px; /*Width of left frame div*/
float:left;
background-image:url(../images/varioCatering02_02.png);
color: white;
}

#framecontentRight{
left: auto;
right: 0; 
float:right;
width: 320px; /*Width of right frame div*/

background-image:url();
color: white;
}

#maincontent{

width:960px;

}
.innertube{
margin: 15px; /*Margins for inner DIV inside each DIV (to provide padding)*/
}

#divleft
{
    float:left;
}
#divright
{
    float:right;
}
 p
 {

    text-align:justify; 
    padding:10px;
    line-height:1.5;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
 }
```

And Html code where it is not working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>dimari - efficient customer solutions for your industry</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image:url();
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
-->
</style>
<link href="css/CssStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="framecontentLeft"> </div>
<div align="center">
<div  id="maincontent">
<div style="height:10px;"></div>
  <div id="divleft">LogoImage with hyperlink</div>
  <div id="divright"> <a class="topLink" href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a class="topLink" href="Impressum.html">Impressum</a> </div>

  <div style="height:80px"> </div>
  <div align="center"  style="margin-bottom:10px;">BannerImage</div>
  <div id="maincontent" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
    <div id="divright" > <b class="MainHeading">Hyperlink</a></b> <b class="MainHeading">HyperLink</b> </div>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div id="maincontent" >
    <div id="ContentTable">
      <div id="divleft">
        <div align="left">
          <h3 class="HeadingOfContentBox" style="text-align:left;padding:10px; margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px">Schulen/Eltern</h3>
        </div>
        <p class="ContentText" style="width:960px;"> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="maincontent">
    <div id="ContentTable"  style="height:450px;">
      <div style="float:left; margin-left:15px;display: inline;" ><span style="text-align:left" >
        <h4 class="ContentText" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;padding:10px;"> Argumente:</h4>
        <ul>
          <li> <span class="ContentText">Bargeldloses Bezahlen</span></li>
          <li class="ContentText">Sicherer Online Login </li>
          <li class="ContentText">Abrechnung pro Gramm > Kind dosiert sich je nach Hunger Essen > wenn mehr Hunger, Nachtisch holen und bequem wieder per Karte bezahlen </li>
          <li class="ContentText"> Schnellere Essensausgabe > Kind/Lehrer mehr Zeit zum Essen an sich </li>
          <li class="ContentText">Essen ohne Vorbestellung </li>
          <li class="ContentText">Sicherer online Login </li>
          <li class="ContentText">Übersichtlichkeit: Nutzungsdaten, Bankdaten, Guthaben, Gekauftes Essen </li>
          <li class="ContentText"> Anmeldung auch ohne Emailadresse, einfach telefonisch </li>
          <li class="ContentText">Ampelstatus im online Account: Angabe wie viel Restguthaben vorhanden </li>
          <li class="ContentText">Automat. Benachrichtigung über Restguthaben </li>
        </ul>
        </span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="maincontent">
       <div id="ContentTable">
     <p>
 <!--    Add your text here-->
 <!--    Add your text here-->
 <!--    Add your text here-->


  </p>
  <p></p>
  </div>
       </div>

</div>
</div>

<div id="framecontentRight"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a little bit too much code. What is exactly the part that does not show correctly? What is the problem?

Comment: Rendering differences in browsers are, sadly, very common. Please point out what exactly doesn't get rendered properly. Consider adding a screenshot or a live link.

Comment: @user701944: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is great for demonstrating HTML/CSS JavaScript problems you’re having.

Comment: what is issue say clearly. I check it!!

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not Firefox, you're code is wrong." Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work.

Answer (score -1):

I tried with my mozilla browser its looks perfect if u getting the problem just copy that particular css line and as example `background : #fff;` and add this line `-moz-background : #fff;` now the css look like this

```
-moz-background : #fff;
background : #fff;
```

both will be there...... moz will be make mozilla compatible another one for all browser support.... i hope this will be help you

Comment: You are replying to an over six-year old thread that has lost its relevance today. In addition, your suggested fix is even more irrelevant in that no browser, especially firefox, has needed a vendor prefix for the `background` property nearly since their inception.